# Choosing a DAC for Amateur Radio applications

Tags: digital-logic, rf, ham-radio

I'm looking to make a software defined radio, and I'm currently looking at what DAC to choose.  I'm fairly new to this area of RF design, so I don't know what specs to look for.  Most of my signals will be ~14MHz SSB transmissions (focusing on the transmitter right now).  How many MSPS per second will my DAC need?  Also, what bit depth should I be looking at?  I've seen other designs use a low-frequency DAC, and the only reason I can see this working is if they use a frequency upconverter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after learning more about radios in general, I learned that you don't necessarily need to sample at 14MHz to digitally read a 14MHz signal.  You can use a local oscillator and an RF mixer to down-convert the 14MHz down to something easier, like 1MHz.  This is what you sample with the DAC.  So the required DAC really depends on what intermediate frequency you choose.